# response.write text/plain compare with jQuery AJAX DataType text

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have the following javascript/jquery syntax which asynchronously gets data from `AWebpageThatProducesTextResult.aspx`.

That webpage produces `text/plain` output that is either `SUCCESS` or `FAIL` and has the following settings

```
            Response.Clear(); //clear all prior output
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain;"; /*we just need a plain response so use text only*/
            Response.Write("SUCCESS"); /*or FAIL, depending on supplied*/ 
            Response.End();
```

However, I can't seem to get how I can compare `success: function (data` to the result of the jQuery `$.ajax` data result, (please refer to the commented lines for additional info

```
        $.ajax("Main/pAdministrator/AWebpageThatProducesTextResult.aspx?ver=111",
        {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text', //we just need to know if it succeded or failed, so use text
            data: {
                action: 'logIn',
                uname: $("#txtUsername").val(),
                pword: $("#txtPassword").val(),
                ipadr: hisIP
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) { //on success. 

                 //has  result.. bu does not redirect. damn. HOW DO I PROPERLY DO A   CONDITION?
                 if (data === 'SUCCESS')
                 {
                    window.location.replace("Home.aspx");
                 }
                else {
                     swal(data); //always goes here even if the login is 
                                   //correct! even if it says "SUCCESS"!
                 }
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { 
            }

        });
```

how can I properly do the `data === 'SUCCESS'` comparison? I think that is the root of the problem

Comment: Have you tried enter debug in the line "if (data === 'SUCCESS')" ? using developers tools.

Comment: I have tried that condition in visual studio, but it didn't work